# VBA Excel Loop copy data based on matching values

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I'm quite new to Excel VBA and I'm stuck on the following issue.
I have a table I'd like to transpose into a new one like this:

[image: results of table transposition]

Each unique value in column A can have several distinct cells in column B (the number of cells varies). I'd like to continue the loop of copying from column B only if values in column A of both table match, but if they don't match then go to the next row and do the same.

Not sure if this is clear, but hopefully the included image will help. Any help is hugely appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the job. Update it with your worksheet name

```
Sub transpose()
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c, Key
    Dim i As Long

    ' Change to your worksheet
    With Sheet4
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))

        Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For Each c In rng
            ReDim tmp(1 To 1)
            If Not Dict.exists(c.Value2) Then Dict.Add Key:=c.Value2, Item:=tmp
            tmp = Dict(c.Value2)

            tmp(UBound(tmp)) = c.Offset(0, 1).Value2
            ReDim Preserve tmp(LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp) + 1)
            Dict(c.Value2) = tmp
        Next c

        ' Set to your destination
        With .Cells(1, 5)
            Range(.Offset(1, 0), .Offset(Dict.Count, 0)).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Dict.keys)
            For Each Key In Dict.keys
                i = i + 1
                tmp = Dict(Key)
                Range(.Offset(i, 1), .Offset(i, UBound(Dict(Key)))).Value2 = Dict(Key)
            Next Key
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```